# Subtracting data frames in Python returning NaN in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to subtract the second columns of two csv files(mycsv.csv, mycsv2.csv), while keeping the first columns of both the same. It does the latter perfectly fine as you can see below, but the prices columns (2 and 4), just give back NaN.

```
     col2  col4
col1            
MMM    NaN   NaN
WBAI   NaN   NaN
WUBA   NaN   NaN
EGHT   NaN   NaN
AHC    NaN   NaN
```

I don't know where this error is coming from, so I apologize for some much code. Thank you for any help you can give!

```
data_sheet1 = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\sss\\Downloads\\Book1.xlsx')
data_impor = data_sheet1['DDD'].tolist()

def get_ohlc(symbols): 
    data = get_quotes(symbol=symbols)
    symbols_and_lastPrices = [] #create empty list
    for symbol in symbols:
        symbols_and_lastPrices.append([symbol, data[symbol]['lastPrice']]) #append [symbol, lastPrice]-pairs to list.
    return symbols_and_lastPrices #return list


csv_data = get_ohlc(data_impor) #save returned list

#write csv

with open ("mycsv.csv", "w" , newline='' ) as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)

    thewriter.writerow(['col1', 'col2'])
    thewriter.writerows(csv_data) #write all data rows at the same time

with open('mycsv.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)

def get_ohlc(symbols): 
    data = get_quotes(symbol=symbols)
    symbols_and_lastPrices = [] #create empty list
    for symbol in symbols:
        symbols_and_lastPrices.append([symbol, data[symbol]['lastPrice']]) #append [symbol, lastPrice]-pairs to list.
    return symbols_and_lastPrices #return list

time.sleep(2)

csv2_data = get_ohlc(data_impor) #save returned list

#write csv

with open ("mycsv2.csv", "w" , newline='' ) as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)

    thewriter.writerow(['col3', 'col4'])
    thewriter.writerows(csv2_data) #write all data rows at the same time

with open('mycsv2.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)

df1  = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv', index_col = 'col1')
df2  = pd.read_csv('mycsv2.csv', index_col = 'col3')
df3 = df1.sub(df2)
print(df3.head())
```

Comment: are the indices aligned? you are getting NaN because of non matching indices.

Comment: they have the same first column (1 and 3) and have the same number of rows and columns, so yes they are aligned

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the initial import of the document.

Here:
data_sheet1 = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\sss\Downloads\Book1.xlsx')
data_impor = data_sheet1['DDD'].tolist()

You are only importing the first column and the rest of the data is not being saved to data_impor

Then you pass this data to the get_ohlc function but it never receives any data for the other columns. Also, why are you defining the get_ohlc function twice?

Comment: the other columns are the last price. When I print the other columns (2 and 4 ), they display just fine. Defining get_ohlc twice was a copy and paste error, sorry

Comment: csv_data = get_ohlc(data_impor), assigns csvdata to the output of get_ohlc() when the symbol listed in the excel sheet is the symbol used to send to the api